# Problem connecting to XRDP... (Windows 10 RDP to Ubuntu XRDP)

Tags: remote-desktop, lxde, remote, remote-access, xrdp

I have XRDP and LXDE insatalled on my linux machine, and I use RDP to connect to it remotely. Every time I try to connect to my Linux machine after I restart it, about 50% of the time I am unable to connect from Windows 10 RDP, I just get a standard timeout error. Only solution that I found is to just restart the machine and try connect again until it works. It usually works the second time. Once I successful connected into the machine the first time, I will have no problem connecting after. However once I restart the machine, the same problem will happen again.

Here is my UFW rule: 3389/tcp ALLOW xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(my IP)
18.04 LTS

Comment: What is your release of Ubuntu/Lubuntu?

Comment: @guiverc 18.04 LTS